# PHP Warning on wp_insert_post() at wp-includes/kses.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using wp_insert_post to take the html of a file and automatically create a post. I have a function that searches a directory, opening and extracting the correct html. The files have dates (which is why i use the subsrt() below). The html is a string, as is anything else I would use for content.

```
<?PHP
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/createpost.php");
$dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/html";
$files = scandir($dir);
$date = (string) date("Ymd");
foreach($files as  $value){
    if((substr($value,5,8)) == $date){
            $html = file_get_contents($dir."/".$value);
            createpost($value, $html);
            }
}
```

The above works. below is the createpost().

```
<?php
function createpost($post_title, $post_content){
require_once("/var/www/wp-load.php");
$mypost = array(
  'ID'             => $post_id,//[ <post id> ] //Are you updating an existing post?
  'menu_order'     => $menu_order,//[ <order> ] //If new post is a page, it sets the order in        which it should appear in the tabs.
  'comment_status' => $comment_status,//[ 'closed' | 'open' ] // 'closed' means no comments.
  'ping_status'    => $ping_status,//[ 'closed' | 'open' ] // 'closed' means pingbacks or trackbacks turned off
  'pinged'         => $pinged,//[ ? ] //?
  'post_author'    => $post_author,//[ <user ID> ] //The user ID number of the author.
  'post_category'  => $post_category,//[ array(<category id>, <...>) ] //post_category no longer exists, try wp_set_post_terms() for setting a post's categories
 'post_content'   => "[raw]\n\n".$post_content."\n\n[/raw]",//[ <the text of the post> ] //The full text of the post.
 'post_date'      => $post_date,//[ Y-m-d H:i:s ] //The time post was made.
  'post_date_gmt'  => $post_date_gmt,//[ Y-m-d H:i:s ] //The time post was made, in GMT.
  'post_excerpt'   => $post_excerpt,//[ <an excerpt> ] //For all your post excerpt needs.
  'post_name'      => $post_name,//[ <the name> ] // The name (slug) for your post
  'post_parent'    => $post_parent,//[ <post ID> ] //Sets the parent of the new post.
  'post_password'  => $post_password,//[ ? ] //password for post?
  'post_status'    => 'private',//[ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | 'custom_registered_status' ] //Set the status of the new post.
 'post_title'     => $post_title,//[ <the title> ] //The title of your post.
 'post_type'      => $post_type,//[ 'post' | 'page' | 'link' | 'nav_menu_item' | 'custom_post_type' ] //You may want to insert a regular post, page, link, a menu item or some custom post type
  'tags_input'     => $tags_input,//[ '<tag>, <tag>, <...>' ] //For tags.
  'to_ping'        => $to_ping,//[ ? ] //?
  'tax_input'      => $tax_input//[ array( 'taxonomy_name' => array( 'term', 'term2', 'term3' ) ) ] // support for custom taxonomies. 
);  
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $mypost );
}
?>
```

when this is all run, i get the following infinite error and the post is never created:

```
PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1146

PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1146

PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/wp-includes/kses.php on line 1146....
```

If I comment out or change the content of the html file this runs fine. It looks like there is something in the html, but regardless of the files contents it is being seen as a string.  What does this warning refer to? Any ideas on getting around it?

Comment: You are just calling `createpost($value, $html);` with two parameters but where other variables (`$post_id, $menu_order` e.t.c) come from ? Also, you have the clue `line 1146` what in this line ?

Comment: I tried it excluding the other variables with the same result. Here is what the warning is referencing:
`function wp_kses_named_entities($matches) {
        global $allowedentitynames;

        if ( empty($matches[1]) )
                return '';

        $i = $matches[1];
        return ( ( ! in_array($i, $allowedentitynames) ) ? "&amp;$i;" : "&$i;" );
}`

Comment: you dont have to `require_once("/var/www/wp-load.php");`

Comment: other thing is go learn about wp_insert_post on codex

Comment: This code is really weird... Where is it running? Standalone, a plugin, a theme, a widget, a shortcode...?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm still stuck. Would I need to do anything special like htmlentities() since im getting html code? `file_get_contents('/../../../doc.html')`. I noticed when I do this, `$a = ("<html>my html code</html>");` the closing `");` is not recognized and the scripting colors are not changing to that of a closed statement, however all brackets,braces, etc are closed in the html code. thoughts?

Comment: brasofilo, This is running standalone. essentially all outside of wp aside from using wp_insert_post().

Comment: To follow up here, the error was due to wp_insert_post filtering the HTML code that is in the post_content variable. The solution was to remove filters, add the post, and reactivate filters. `kses_remove_filters(); // remove filter 
wp_insert_post( $mypost ); //write post 
kses_init_filters(); // put back filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off kses filters. The filter is actually changing the code you want to insert. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/kses_remove_filters/

Turn them off right before the insert then turn them back on.